# Creating a 4-hr time interval using a reference column in R

Tags: r, datetime, intervals

I want to create a 4-hrs interval using a reference column from a data frame. I have a data frame like this one:

> ```
> species<-"ABC"
> ind<-rep(1:4,each=24)
> hour<-rep(seq(0,23,by=1),4)
> depth<-runif(length(ind),1,50)
>
> df<-data.frame(cbind(species,ind,hour,depth))
> df$depth<-as.numeric(df$depth)
> ```

What I would like is to create a new column (without changing the information or dimensions of the original data frame) that could look at my hour column (reference column) and based on that value will give me a 4-hrs time interval. For example, if the value from the hour column is between 0 and 3, then the value in new column will be 0; if the value is between 4 and 7 the value in the new column will be 4, and so on... In excel I used to use the floor/ceiling functions for this, but in R they are not exactly the same. Also, if someone has an easier suggestion for this using the original date/time data that could work too. In my original script I used the function as.POSIXct to get the date/time data, and from there my hour column.

I appreciate your help,

Comment: I think you should look at `?cut`, particularly `?cut.Date`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what about taking the column of hours, converting it to integers, and using integer division to get the floor? something like this

```
# convert hour to integer (hour is currently a col of factors)
i <- as.numeric(levels(df$hour))[df$hour]

# make new column
df$interval <- (i %/% 4) * 4
```

Comment: @ aleph_null Based on this same example, how would you find an interval of hours between 6 and 17 (seq(6,17,1)) and name it "daytimes" in another column? The same for nighttimes, which will be the remaining hours that are not daytimes?

Answer (score 2):

tip number 1, don't use `cbind` to create a data.frame with differing type of columns, everything gets coerced to the same type (in this case factor)

`findInterval` or `cut` would seem appropriate here.

```
df <- data.frame(species,ind,hour,depth)
# copy
df2 <- df
df2$fourhour <- c(0,4,8,12,16,20)[findInterval(df$hour, c(0,4,8,12,16,20))]
```

Answer (score 2):

Though there is probably a simpler way, here is one attempt.

Make your data.frame not using `cbind` first though, so `hour` is not a `factor` but `numeric`

```
df <- data.frame(species,ind,hour,depth)
```

Then:

```
df$interval <- factor(findInterval(df$hour,seq(0,23,4)),labels=seq(0,23,4))
```

Result:

```
> head(df)
  species ind hour    depth interval
1     ABC   1    0 23.11215        0
2     ABC   1    1 10.63896        0
3     ABC   1    2 18.67615        0
4     ABC   1    3 28.01860        0
5     ABC   1    4 38.25594        4
6     ABC   1    5 30.51363        4
```

You could also make the labels a bit nicer like:

```
cutseq <- seq(0,23,4)
df$interval <- factor(
                       findInterval(df$hour,cutseq),
                       labels=paste(cutseq,cutseq+3,sep="-")
                     )
```

Result:

```
> head(df)
  species ind hour    depth interval
1     ABC   1    0 23.11215      0-3
2     ABC   1    1 10.63896      0-3
3     ABC   1    2 18.67615      0-3
4     ABC   1    3 28.01860      0-3
5     ABC   1    4 38.25594      4-7
6     ABC   1    5 30.51363      4-7
```

Comment: Based on this same example, how would you find an interval of hours between 6 and 17 (seq(6,17,1)) and name it "daytimes" in another column? The same for nighttimes, which will be the remaining hours that are not daytimes?

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on my comment, since I think you're ultimately looking for actual dates at some point...

Some sample hourly data:

```
set.seed(1)
mydata <- data.frame(species = "ABC",
                     ind = rep(1:4, each=24),
                     depth = runif(96, 1, 50),
                     datetime = seq(ISOdate(2000, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0), 
                                    by = "1 hour", length.out = 96))
list(head(mydata), tail(mydata))
# [[1]]
#   species ind    depth            datetime
# 1     ABC   1 14.00992 2000-01-01 00:00:00
# 2     ABC   1 19.23407 2000-01-01 01:00:00
# 3     ABC   1 29.06981 2000-01-01 02:00:00
# 4     ABC   1 45.50218 2000-01-01 03:00:00
# 5     ABC   1 10.88241 2000-01-01 04:00:00
# 6     ABC   1 45.02109 2000-01-01 05:00:00
# 
# [[2]]
#    species ind     depth            datetime
# 91     ABC   4 12.741841 2000-01-04 18:00:00
# 92     ABC   4  3.887784 2000-01-04 19:00:00
# 93     ABC   4 32.472125 2000-01-04 20:00:00
# 94     ABC   4 43.937191 2000-01-04 21:00:00
# 95     ABC   4 39.166819 2000-01-04 22:00:00
# 96     ABC   4 40.068132 2000-01-04 23:00:00
```

Transforming that data using `cut` and `format`:

```
mydata <- within(mydata, {
    hourclass <- cut(datetime, "4 hours")             # Find the intervals
    hourfloor <- format(as.POSIXlt(hourclass), "%H")  # Display just the "hour"
})
list(head(mydata), tail(mydata))
# [[1]]
#   species ind    depth            datetime           hourclass hourfloor
# 1     ABC   1 14.00992 2000-01-01 00:00:00 2000-01-01 00:00:00        00
# 2     ABC   1 19.23407 2000-01-01 01:00:00 2000-01-01 00:00:00        00
# 3     ABC   1 29.06981 2000-01-01 02:00:00 2000-01-01 00:00:00        00
# 4     ABC   1 45.50218 2000-01-01 03:00:00 2000-01-01 00:00:00        00
# 5     ABC   1 10.88241 2000-01-01 04:00:00 2000-01-01 04:00:00        04
# 6     ABC   1 45.02109 2000-01-01 05:00:00 2000-01-01 04:00:00        04
# 
# [[2]]
#    species ind     depth            datetime           hourclass hourfloor
# 91     ABC   4 12.741841 2000-01-04 18:00:00 2000-01-04 16:00:00        16
# 92     ABC   4  3.887784 2000-01-04 19:00:00 2000-01-04 16:00:00        16
# 93     ABC   4 32.472125 2000-01-04 20:00:00 2000-01-04 20:00:00        20
# 94     ABC   4 43.937191 2000-01-04 21:00:00 2000-01-04 20:00:00        20
# 95     ABC   4 39.166819 2000-01-04 22:00:00 2000-01-04 20:00:00        20
# 96     ABC   4 40.068132 2000-01-04 23:00:00 2000-01-04 20:00:00        20
```

Note that your new "hourclass" variable is a factor and the new "hourfloor" variable is character, but you can easily change those, even during the `within` stage.

```
str(mydata)
# 'data.frame':    96 obs. of  6 variables:
#  $ species  : Factor w/ 1 level "ABC": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
#  $ ind      : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
#  $ depth    : num  14 19.2 29.1 45.5 10.9 ...
#  $ datetime : POSIXct, format: "2000-01-01 00:00:00" "2000-01-01 01:00:00" ...
#  $ hourclass: Factor w/ 24 levels "2000-01-01 00:00:00",..: 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 ...
#  $ hourfloor: chr  "00" "00" "00" "00" ...
```